# Remix multiple data sets returned in a loader function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I must be misunderstanding how loader functions work.  My route has a simple form with two select lists.  Each comes from a different database table.  I started with just one, and it looked something like this.

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params, request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    return await getItemTypes("1"); // <-- from Prisma
};
...
const itemTypes = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
...
<select name="itemType">
{itemTypes.map((itemType) =>
  <option key={itemType.itemTypeId} value={itemType.itemTypeId}>
    {itemType.itemTypeName}
  </option>
)}
</select>
```

That all works nicely.  But now I have a second select for itemCategory.  Everything I can find on LoaderFunction seems to suggest that it must return just one response.  So how do I accomplish this?